# How to get idMso Ribbonname of a selected meeting in outlook calendar?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

how can i reference this ribbon (idMso) to display my custom add in group there?
The ribbon is only visible when I select an appointment item. I want to get the item from
the selection with my add in.
But I don't know the idMso of this ribbon. It is not TabMeeting or TabCalender.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon startFromScratch="0">
    <tabs>
      <!--<tab idMso="TabAddIns" insertBeforeMso="TabMail">-->
      <tab idMso="TabMeeting">
        <group id="GetTermine"
               label="SITBS">
           <toggleButton id="OnActionCallback" label="Get Termine" size="large" onAction="OnActionCallback" />
        </group>
      </tab>
        <tab idMso="TabAppointment">
            <group id="GetTermine1"
   label="SITBS">
                <toggleButton id="OnActionCallback1" label="Get Termine" size="large" onAction="OnActionCallback" />
            </group>
        </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

[image: custom group (add in button)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked out the solution.
It's not a normal tab, it's acontextual tab

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="0">
        <contextualTabs>
            <tabSet idMso="TabSetAppointment" visible="true">
                <tab idMso="TabAppointment">
                    <group id="GetTermineApptCont" label="SITBS">
                        <button id="OnActionCallbackCont" label="Sync Berichte" imageMso="Synchronize" size="large" onAction="OnActionCallback" />
                    </group>
                </tab>
            </tabSet>
        </contextualTabs>
        <tabs>
            <tab idMso="TabCalendar" >
                <group id="GetTermineCal" label="SITBS">
                    <button id="OnActionCallback22" label="Sync Berichte" imageMso="Synchronize" size="large" onAction="OnActionCallback" />
                </group>
            </tab>
            <tab idMso="TabAppointment" >
                <group id="GetTermineAppt" label="SITBS">
                    <button id="OnActionCallback11" label="Sync Berichte" imageMso="Synchronize" size="large" onAction="OnActionCallback" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```